# add variable to awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I have this awk command that I need to put a date variable in. I'm sure I'm missing some syntax somewhere. Can any experts help me out? Basicaly, I need the date to be variable depending on when the script is run.

```
date=$(date --date="1 month ago" +"%d-%b-%Y")
wget -qO - http://*********/users.csv > users
awk      'NR==1          {print "Primary Comments,Customer Account Number,Transaction Date,Service Description,Quantity,Unit,Price,Service Category,PI\x27sName,Purchaser\x27s Last Name,Short Contributing Center Name,Resource Name,Line Item Assistant,Line Item Comments"}
          FNR==NR        {S[$1]=$2; P[$1]=$3; next}
          $1 in S        {print "Bruker 500 NMR",P[$1],date,"500 MHz",$2/60,"Hour","5","500 MHz",S[$1],$1,"","501 NMR","","" }
          ' FS="," OFS="," OFMT="%.2f" $date users FS=" " wtmp > billing-$inst-$date.csv
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-v` option.

```
awk -v date="$date" ....
```

But GNU awk (`gawk`) has its own time functions, which are documented here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Comment: Was going to answer the same thing. And to add some more sanity to the script, I highly recommend storing the AWK part in a separate file and then doing `awk -v date="$date" -f myscript.awk ...`

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to use the `-v` option but I kept getting an error.  I've figured it out though.